# Polymer Nested Core-Scaffold and Multiple Vertical Scrollbars / Scrolling Extent Issues

Tags: css, polymer, core-elements

I'm having some trouble with the current layout of my polymer site, specifically with regards to nested components and their associated scrollbars.  I'll preface this by stating that by absolutely no means am I a CSS guru.  I wish I was because I probably wouldn't be struggling with this as much as I am.  Also feel free to jump straight to the jsbin URL as my issue may become apparent.

The situation:
I currently have a nested core-scaffold element, whose main content often requires vertical scrolling and thus it's vertical scrollbar becomes active as required.  However, as it is nested, it's container(s) can also have scrollbars enabled.  Ideally, I'd like a single scrollbar on the highest level element which can scroll the scaffold's content to it's full vertical extents, yet also cause the topbar to slide away as it does now when scrolling down.  I've also noticed that the height of the scaffold's main content is determined by the first page that is loaded into it.  Subsequent page loads with different heights does not cause the scrollbar height extents to change accordingly.

Please note that I've simply inserted an iframe loading external content into the scaffold's content section for the purpose of this jsbin demo.  My actual site loads a bunch of data driven collapsible height containers within the content pages, wrapping horizontally as needed.  Due to their collapsibility, their containing page therefore has a dynamic height.  That height can vary from page to page as container heights within them vary.

Here is the jsbin.  Whoever can remove me from this css hell will be considered my hero...

http://jsbin.com/muniqi/1/

Comment: More on this topic on this polymer google group thread:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/iiVEXFm1JmM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my initial jsbin sample code, you'll notice I have specified core-pages height as '100vh' the top level polymer element (i.e. my-app-element).  The second level polymer element (i.e. my-scaffold-page-element), loads within the aforementioned core-pages.  Therefore, the nested scaffold element's maximum height is 100vh.  Further down the chain, when the scaffold-element's main content area's height flows past its host's height limitation, it caused a secondary 'inner' scrollbar to appear, which has a different vertical extent than the original outer scrollbar...so trying to use the outer scrollbar alone doesn't effectively scroll the inner content to its entire vertical extent, forcing you to use the inner scrollbar as well to get the job done.  Ugly to say the least.

Now that I know that is the case, one way to reduce the likelihood of an inner scrollbar appearing for the nested scaffold element's main content area is to change it's parent element's core-pages height to something much greater than 100vh (400vh?).  Doing so solves the problem in a roundabout way.  The outer scrollbar can now be used to scroll the entire vertical extent of the nested scaffold's contents without an inner scrollbar occurring.

In the new jsbin example (below), you can witness the 'fix', which also happens to remove the reliance on core-scaffold, instead preferring to utilize its individual components in a more configurable fashion.

http://jsbin.com/muniqi/3/